# How are high voltage battery banks charged in state of the art applications?

Tags: battery-charging, high-voltage

It seems that a lot of battery banks, whether SLA or Li-Ion are setup in series to get high voltages, sometimes higher than the telco industry standard of 48V (which charges at 56V.)

A high voltage battery bank reduces current and make design of step/up step/down converters used in solar, UPS and automotive industries easier since the voltage difference between the battery bank, let's say a 400V DC link.

Integrated solutions from TI or LTC are limited to around 60V. The highest all-in-one controller from LTC seems to be the LTC4020, that could charge a 48V SLA battery bank, but the LM5117, although not a battery charger IC per se, falls short in its specifications for a 48V battery bank (at least, Webench refuses to calculate a solution, and an LTspice simulation gives oscillatory output at such high voltages, and the supply voltage from a preconditioning converter needs to be at the very limit of the high DC input range, 63V vs 65V.)

How does the industry do it? I assume that they use topologies like flyback converters and implement a in-house digital control solution for battery management, is that correct?

Comment: People who charge 400-1000 V EV batteries design their own, they don't go looking for a one chip solution in a catalogue (because there aren't any there, too much current, too much voltage, too much power). If you're interested, some car makers use the drive motor itself as an inductor in the charger topology - there have been several papers published on how best to sequence the motor windings in this mode to produce zero torque and minimise the noise.

Answer (score 2):

High-voltage chargers produce high voltage through switch-mode transformers. The ICs operate at low voltages:

1. The voltage feedback is through a voltage divider
2. The current feedback is through a low resistance shunt resistor
3. The output drive is at MOSFET gate voltages, about 10 V

What sees high voltages is MOSFETS or IGBTs, not the ICs.

> Are there any BMS designs that would allow charging individual batteries

Charging is not a BMS function. Yes, there are systems that use one charger per cell. They are seen mostly in chargers for UAVs ("drones"). But, again that's a charging function, not a BMS function.

> thus require complex isolation schemes.

Complex? No, not complex. Practically every charger and every power supply in the world uses a transformer for isolation. Nothing complex about that. (The exception is a off-line, low-power power supply found in LED lamps and keep-alive power supplies in some consumer products.)

Comment: Agreed for point 1,2 and 3, there are also other inputs like UVLO and RAMP emulation that use a voltage divider so this should be no issue. Then there is the issue of supplying power to the IC from high voltages, but a zener of TL431 could be used to take care of this. In the end, I shoud have rather said costlier than complex. Isolation means adding a switching transformer. The question remains why manufacturers specify limited voltage ratings in the datasheets, following your logic, it would concern only the rating for the IC supply voltage (Vin).

Comment: "The question remains why manufacturers specify limited voltage ratings " Because those are complete converters: they include the MOSFETs, so they see the high voltage. The ICs I am referring to are just controllers: the MOSFETs are external. That's why they don't see the high voltage.